# Call multiple controller Actions from single controller Action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Currently i have 5 controllers(cn1 to cn5) and each controller have same action(createFile)which will create some files needed for particular module.Due to some requirement i need to keep it separately only, So currently we are calling each action according to our need.now i am trying to create a single action(i will call in browser) that will call all these actions one by one.still i want to call the action separately whenever I want so i cant change my separate controller actions.and also in future new modules may come so in  minimal modification i should able to accommodate new controller-action call to my new action.

my one controller action is given bellow

```
    [Route("createFile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
    {
        try
        {

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

              //file creation code
             //if success
                response.Content = new StringContent("Filter JSON file Error", Encoding.UTF8);
            else
                response.Content = new StringContent("Filter JSON file is created", Encoding.UTF8);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

currently am accessing this action in browser URL,so for 5 modules i need to call 5 times but i should keep the code like this only.Can we achieve this all controller call in single action.something like i will call controller/action in browser then it will automatically call these all actions.

Comment: You must bear in mind that an action is meant to return a response back to the browser. What do you want to happen when you call the five actions? Do you expect five responses back to the browser? Or, do you want only one response?

Comment: You could create a controller with an action that returns the urls of the data locations of the modules. Then use javascript to call the returned urls one by one. If that is not what you want, I think you should move the logic for creating the files down a layer in a seperate component and have both the module controllers and the shared controller call the same underlying components.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ:i want only one response

Comment: @user3501613 In this case, you need to extract the content of each action into a separate method, then call the five methods from the one action that you want. As for the other actions, they can call their respective methods so that they still function when called individually.